# NaNd ago in chat stars list?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I've been seeing this strange behavior on the starred list in the Tavern. It could be because, well, it's The Tavern, but...

[image: Official Screenshot of the Stackoverflow Baseball Team]

[image: A freehand for @balpha]

Confirmed in Safari 5 for Mac OS X 10.6.6 Snow Leopard. Tested both with and without userscripts enabled.

The problem seems to go away when the page is refreshed or when I star something.

Comment: It's because none of those are mine; start starring my posts instead of those people

Comment: I saw this same problem in Gaming's [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) earlier today. The went away when I reloaded the page.  Actually, now that I look again, I'm seeing it *now* in The Bridge.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm using Firefox 3.6.12 on WinXP.

Comment: IE8 on XP, saw this in a few rooms on chat.stackexchange. Only in live chat, though. Not in the room's info pages.

Comment: I'm using Firefox on Win 7, same problem. Guess it's site wide...

Comment: This is the day after the seventh day, the day when all SOIS employees rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Chrome is more flexible in parsing date strings than the rest of the browsers. For now, I'll only enable it for browsers that manage to handle it; I'll look at getting it to work in the rest tomorrow.

**Edit:** Should be fixed now.

Comment: It's not only Chrome. See [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80404/nand-ago-in-chat-stars-list/80511#80511).

Comment: @sbi Chrome was the only browser that *didn't* have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not only Chrome. I'm seeing this in FF (3.6.13), too:

[image: NaNd]

I noticed this first a few days ago. It comes and goes. I see it nowhere else on the SE sites.

Comment: Are you seeing it with fresh Javascript? I.e. younger than about 18 hours?

Comment: @balpha: When I saw it again I searched meta for "NaNd" and added this answer.